# Import the 2nd row of multiple text files into Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to import the second row of multiple tab delimited text files from a folder into excel starting at row 2.

I have recorded a macro that imports the 2nd row of a SINGLE tab delimited text file into excel starting at row 2. (I have a header row in the excel sheet). I have also found code that will import multiple text files into excel. I am having trouble putting them together. I want to add the multiple file import functionality to my recorded macro.

Here is the code I recorded that imports the second row of a single text file into row 2 in excel. I want this code to import the second row of multiple text files into Excel starting at row 2, then row 3 etc...

```
Sub Import()
'
' Import Macro
'

'
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\t830439\Desktop\test\BTWP004217_2017_6_29_12'14'03'0001.upl", _
    Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
    .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "BTWP004217_2017_6_29_12'14'03'0001"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileStartRow = 2
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierNone
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Here is the code to import multiple text files. I need the 'Loop through all files' functionality added to my recorded code above. I have already added the correct Reference for this code to run.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\t830439\Desktop\test")

' set the starting point to write the data to
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Open the file
    Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

    ' Read the file one line at a time
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

        ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
        Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

        ' Put data on one row in active sheet
        For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
            cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
        Next

        ' Move to next row
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    FileText.Close
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks.

EDIT - UPDATE--------------------------------------------

I've merged the code, but cannot get it to Loop.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet3()
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\t830439\Desktop\test")

' set the starting point to write the data to
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Open the file
    Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

    ' Read the file one line at a time
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

        ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
        'Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

        ' Put data on one row in active sheet
      '  For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
         '  cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
       ' Next

        'Move to next row
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)



     With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\t830439\Desktop\test\BTWP004217_2017_6_29_12'14'03'0001.upl", _
    Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
   ' .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "BTWP004217_2017_6_29_12'14'03'0001"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileStartRow = 2
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierNone
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

    Loop

    ' Clean up
    FileText.Close
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A2:AA2")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm

Comment: This is close. I successfully removed the 'copy filename into column A' and now have the string starting in column A.

I need help with:
1. Import the text as Tab Delimited
2. Import into the Active Sheet, not a new sheet

Comment: Ok, for #2, change this line: 
Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

It should be something like:
Set BaseWks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

OR
Set BaseWks = ActiveSheet


I think...can you try and see if it works.  As for #1...hummmm...I'm not sure.  I didn't even realize that was an issue when you are doing the process this way.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that and I'll try to create another macro to covert column A to delimited text.

Comment: Both suggestions worked. Also, I recorded the 'text to column' macro and added it just above the BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit and it works great!!! Thanks for the help!!!!!

Comment: Happy to help.  Just keep an open mind about these kinds of things as you go forward.  Sometimes there are memory limits, like the 1,048,576 row limit in Excel, but really, there is no limit to what you can do with technology.  Perhaps the only limitation, is your own imagination.